# Reflect the user changes to colors after DialogPage setting changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I'm building an extension to change the color of different programming constructs in C# and VB, I use Roslyn APIs for that. I use `Package` and `DialogPage` to give the user the option for changing the colors, Here's my option page:

[image]

What I want is to change the colors as soon as user changes the color setting and `SaveSettingsToStorage` event happens. When this event happens I call `Settings.Save` to save the settings, also in my Settings class I have `Settings.SettingsUpdated` event that I can subscribe to, but I don't know what should I call when this event happens to reflect the user changes on colors, in other words, updating the colors, Here's the save event that happens for `DialogPage`:

```
public override void SaveSettingsToStorage()
    {
        var settings = new PresetColors
        {

            Interface = Interface.ToMediaColor(),
            Class = Class.ToMediaColor(),
            AbstractClass = AbstractClass.ToMediaColor(),
            StaticClass = StaticClass.ToMediaColor(),
            Struct = Struct.ToMediaColor(),
            Enum = Enum.ToMediaColor(),
            EnumConstant = EnumConstant.ToMediaColor(),
            Constructor = Constructor.ToMediaColor(),
            Attribute = Attribute.ToMediaColor(),
            Field = Field.ToMediaColor(),
            Namespace = Namespace.ToMediaColor(),
            Method = Method.ToMediaColor(),
            StaticMethod = StaticMethod.ToMediaColor(),
            ExtensionMethod = ExtensionMethod.ToMediaColor(),
            AutomaticProperty = AutomaticProperty.ToMediaColor(),
            TypeParameter = Parameter.ToMediaColor()
        };
        State.Settings.Save(settings);
    }
```

What I use to change the colors are `ClassificationFormatDefinition`, a class that implements `ITagger<IClassificationTag>` and `ITaggerProvider`, here my tagger for instance:

```
internal class ColorCoderTagger : ITagger<IClassificationTag>
{
    private ITextBuffer _buffer;
    private readonly ColorCoderTaggerServices _colorCoderTaggerServices;
    private readonly ClassificationTypeFactory _classificationTypeFactory;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IClassificationType> classificationTypeDictionary;
    private ProviderCache _cache;

    public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged;

    public ColorCoderTagger(ITextBuffer buffer, IClassificationTypeRegistryService classificationRegistry)
    {
        this._buffer = buffer;
        _classificationTypeFactory = new ClassificationTypeFactory(classificationRegistry);
        classificationTypeDictionary = _classificationTypeFactory.CreateClassificationTypes();
        _colorCoderTaggerServices = new ColorCoderTaggerServices();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<IClassificationTag>> GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        if (spans.Count == 0)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ITagSpan<IClassificationTag>>();
        }

        var cacheStatus = _colorCoderTaggerServices.ManageCache(ref _cache, spans, _buffer);

        if (cacheStatus == CacheState.NotResolved)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ITagSpan<IClassificationTag>>();
        }

        return _colorCoderTaggerServices.GetClassificationTags(_cache, spans, classificationTypeDictionary);
    }
}
```

Here's my class to manage cache:

```
public class ProviderCache
{
    public Workspace Workspace { get; private set; }
    public Document Document { get; private set; }
    public SemanticModel SemanticModel { get; private set; }
    public SyntaxNode SyntaxRoot { get; private set; }
    public ITextSnapshot Snapshot { get; private set; }

    public static async Task<ProviderCache> Resolve(ITextBuffer buffer, ITextSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        var workspace = buffer.GetWorkspace();
        var document = snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
        if (document == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return new ProviderCache
        {
            Workspace = workspace,
            Document = document,
            SemanticModel = semanticModel,
            SyntaxRoot = syntaxRoot,
            Snapshot = snapshot
        };
    }
}
```

Right now, I have to close and open the visual studio for the changes to take effect. I can change the color settings through fonts and colors option of visual studio, but I want to change it through my own ColorCoder option page,  I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `IVsFontAndColorStorage` which in contained inside `VisualStudio.Shell.Interop`. Here a small sample code:

```
    public void Save(IDictionary<String, ColorableItemInfo[]> classifications)
    {
        Guid category = new Guid(Guids.TextEditorCategory);

        uint flags = (uint)(__FCSTORAGEFLAGS.FCSF_LOADDEFAULTS
                          | __FCSTORAGEFLAGS.FCSF_PROPAGATECHANGES);

        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        var hr = _colorStorage.Storage.OpenCategory(ref category, flags);
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(hr);

        try
        {
            foreach (var classification in classifications)
            {
                hr = _colorStorage.Storage.SetItem(classification.Key, classification.Value);
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(hr);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _colorStorage.Storage.CloseCategory();
        }
    }
```

I've used it in the code base for [ColorCoder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xellarix.ColorCoder) visual studio extension. Here is its [github repository](https://github.com/HamidMosalla/VisualStudio-ColorCoder/blob/master/ColorCoder/ColorCoderCore/ColorManager.cs) if you need more code related to this.